# Converting image from database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

```
cnn.Open();

cmd.CommandText = "select * from Slab  where s_flatno=" + textBox1.Text;

SqlDataReader dr1;
dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (dr1.Read())
{
        byte[] img1 = File.ReadAllBytes(dr1[7].ToString());
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img1);
        Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr1[1].ToString(), dr1[4].ToString(), dr1[5].ToString(), dr1[6].ToString(),dr1[7].ToString());
        count = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString());
   }

lblcount.Text = count.ToString();
dr1.Close();
cnn.Close()
```

In the above code i'm accessing data from database to data grid view but in the table im having images in byte code, how can i convert images from byte to image and how can i update in DataGridView in windows application in c#.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the _img_ variable that you create. You can try to put it into the row :).

Answer (score 2):

You are using `ToString()` on the reader's column, but that will not work as the data type of the column is `byte[]`. You should use the following:

```
byte[] imageData = ( byte[] )dr1[7];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData);
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dr1[1].ToString(), dr1[4].ToString(), dr1[5].ToString(), dr1[6].ToString(),dr1[7].ToString());
count = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString());
```

As additional suggestion, you should use clearer variable names as and definitely access the columns in data reader by column name instead of index, because this will break anytime a change in DB happens and the order of columns changes.

Comment: It that helped, please consider accepting the answer so that the question is resolved.